# Android app for feedback on plosives and sibilance?

Tags: android, educational, speech-recognition

My girlfriend's son is speech delayed, and has problems pronouncing 'b's, 'p's, and 's'es. Is there an Android app that will give some feedback based on plosives or sibilance sound? I think getting some kind of reward, even if it is just a flashy graphic on the screen, would help speed his development.

I've searched the play store for speech therapy apps, but they are centered around reading and word pronunciation. He's way to young for that, and that's not his problem area.

Comment: For English, right?

Comment: Yes, though I'm not informed enough about sibilants and plosives to know if they would be close enough in any other language. We're not looking for vowels right now.